# LINQ to Entities .Contains for a tuple (2 foreign keys)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Actually, a colleague of mine asked me this question and I haven't been able to come up with an answer. Here goes.

Given an entity with 2 foreign keys, say

```
public class MyTable
{
   public int Key1 { get; set; }
   public int Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

and 2 lists

```
public ICollection List1 => new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
public ICollection List2 => new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
```

he needs to query for all records where Key1 matches the value from List1 and Key2 matches the value from List2, e.g.

```
Key1 == 1 && Key2 == 4
```

that is, he wants to check for any given tuple from List1 and List2, (1, 4), (2, 5) and (3, 6).

Is there a straightforward way in EF to do this?

Comment: what about (1, 5), are you looking for these cases too?

Comment: Nope, that's what makes the whole thing so tricky.

Comment: Can list have duplicate numbers?

Comment: Yes, there may be duplicates.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `ICollection` type for List1, List2?

Comment: No it may as well be IEnumerable, Tuple or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `for` loop to capture some local variable (in each loop) in the `Where` and use `Concat` (or `Union` - maybe with worse performance) to sum up all the result like this:

```
IQueryable<MyTable> q = null;   
//suppose 2 lists have the same count
for(var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++){
   var k1 = list1[i];
   var k2 = list2[i];
   var s = context.myTables.Where(e => e.Key1 == k1 && e.Key2 == k2); 
   q = q == null ? s : q.Concat(s);
}
//materialize the result
var result = q.ToList();
```

***NOTE:*** we can use `Concat` here because each sub-result should be unique (based on searching the keys). It surely has better performance than `Union` (ensuring uniqueness while we already know the sub-results are all unique beforehand - so it's unnecessary).

If you have a list of `int` (just integral numeric), you can also pair the keys into underscore separated string and use `Contains` normally like this:

```
var stringKeys = list1.Select((e,i) => e + "_" + list2[i]).ToList();
var result = context.myTables.Where(e => stringKeys.Contains(e.Key1 + "_" + e.Key2))
            .ToList();
```

Building an Expression tree is also another approach but it's more complicated while I'm not sure if it has better performance.

Comment: This solution actually works, so we may consider using this approach for the time being.

Comment: @Aredhel this is the easiest solution I can think of. Choosing it or Expression tree is another problem of which performs better (as I said I'm not sure about that). Expression gives out a query like `SELECT ... WHERE boo1 OR boo2 OR ...` while the first code in my answer (with `Concat`) gives out a query like `SELECT ... WHERE boo1 UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE boo2 ...`. Also the answer with Expression tree (posted here) is wrong, there should be some OR expressions but he sequenced all WHERE conditions together which will never be true (always result in empty).

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed to work with Entity framework

```
var tuples = List1.Cast<int>().Zip(List2.Cast<int>(), (l, r) => new { l, r });
var results = Orders.Where(o =>
    tuples.Contains(new { l = (int)o.KeyOne, r = (int)o.KeyTwo })
);
```

Or simpler, if you define your lists as `ICollection<int>` or `IList<int>` (etc...):

```
var tuples = List1.Zip(List2, (l, r) => new { l, r });
var results = Orders.Where(o =>
    tuples.Contains(new { l = (int)o.KeyOne, r = (int)o.KeyTwo })
);
```

Comment: That would work for LINQ to Objects but are you sure that it would work for LINQ to Entities?  Remember that a LINQ to Entities query must be able to be converted to SQL code that can be executed on the database.  I'm not saying that your solution wouldn't work but I'm not sure that it would.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You're right, my bad. I've updated the code and tested it (definitely works this time :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a change from `ICollection` to `IList` doesn't remove the need for the `Cast` call.  `Zip` is an extension of `IEnumerable<T>` so what matters is that the interface is generic, which `IList` is not.

Comment: You're right, I'm not paying attention; will update :)

Comment: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: @Aredhel What's the exact code you're using? What I've written above works locally

Comment: var aufgabenIds = new List<int> { 5, 6 };
         var tourIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

         var tuples = aufgabenIds.Zip(tourIds, (l, r) => new { l, r });

         using (var context = new Verwaltung())
         {
            var leistungen = context.LEISTUNGSZUORDNUNG
               .Where(o => tuples.Contains(new { l = (int)o.iAufgabe, r = (int)o.iTour }))
               .ToList();
         }

Comment: @Rob I guess you didn't materialize your query using ToList(), because the query builds fine up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIn(this Table<TSource> table, List<object[]> list) where TSource : class
{
    var query = table.AsQueryable();
    foreach (object[] item in list)
    {
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> expr = WhereInExpression(item);
        query = query.Where(expr);
    }

    return query;
}

static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> WhereInExpression<TSource>(object[] item)
{

   ParameterExpression parameterItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "expr");
   BinaryExpression filter1 = Expression.Equal(LambdaExpression.PropertyOrField(parameterItem, "Key1"),
   Expression.Constant(item[0]));

   BinaryExpression filter2 = Expression.Equal(LambdaExpression.PropertyOrField(parameterItem, "Key2"),

   Expression.Constant(item[1]));

   BinaryExpression filter = LambdaExpression.And(filter1, filter2);

   var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(filter, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterItem });

   expr.Compile();

   return expr;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>() { new object[] { 1, 100 }, new object[] { 1, 101 }, new object[] { 2, 100 } };

var result = db.MyTable.WhereIn<MyTable>(list);
```

Comment: We'd love to give this a shot, unfortunately the keys are of type short? in the model (not our doing, mind) and we can't get past this exception: "The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int16]' and 'System.Int16'."

Comment: If they're nullable, they're not keys... In any case, you can always add a check for `.HasValue` before the `.Equals`

Comment: +1 for suggesting to build an expression tree, that's something which will come in handy further down the road.

Answer (score -1):

Fiddle here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/YyyZBY

```
    var List_1 =  new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var List_2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };

    var TargetList = new List<MyTable>();

    var index1=0;
    var List1 = List_1.Select(x=>new { ind=index1++,value=x });
    var index2=0;
    var List2 = List_2.Select(x=>new { ind=index2++,value=x });

    var values = from l1 in List1
                 join l2 in List2 on l1.ind equals l2.ind
                 select new {value1=l1.value,value2=l2.value };


var result = TargetList.Where(x=>values.Any(y=>y.value1==x.Key1&&y.value2==x.Key2));
```

Comment: This also gives me "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: @Aredhel : it works.. please check the fiddle in answer.

Comment: Yes, it does, but for LINQ to Objects only. Fails for LINQ to Entities locally.